# How to compute 2^h*ceil(i/2^h)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, arithmetic-expressions

Is there an easy way to compute:

```
(2^h)*ceil(i/(2^h))
```

where i and h are integers, without explicitly using the ceiling function?

For example, for (2^h)*floor(i/(2^h)) can be computed using something like

```
i&-(1<<h)
```

which doesn't use the floor function.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you mean with `^` exponentiation and not bitwise XOR. So something like

```
(i + (1 << h) - 1) & (-1 << h)
```

should work.

Comment: Couldn't we use `-1 << h` there and save an operation?

Comment: sorry, could you update the answer to include what @harold mentioned?